# What blogging platforms provide tools for developer-bloggers?

Tags: blogs, markdown

I am looking for a blogging platform that has built in tools for programming-related content.  For example, I've seen blogs that have line-numbers, color-coded line separation, code-formatting and tool tips for copying and pasting code-samples.  Some of these are better than others.  (I'm sure I'm not the only one here who gets annoyed by blog entries with posted source that you can't copy without also copying all the line numbers).  So, my question is what blogging-platform does the community recommend for a developer-oriented blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

er...none that i know of. at the moment, you have to get the bits and pieces together. for my own blog (Blogger, so i'm limited in addons), i use [Highlight code converter](http://andre-simon.de) to generate the display HTML/inline CSS, clean it up a bit (the default settings assume you're creating an entire web page from the code) by removing unnecessary markup, then using it in my blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has the code highligthing feature using some addins, if you are going to host it yourself it will be a very good option to use Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

[BlogDown](https://github.com/thingdown/blogdown) is a static blogging platform, so it can be hosted on GitHub. You can write posts with markdown files, which has great support for code snippets. You can write your own themes and modules for it also. Unlike Jekkyl, BlogDown does not have a compilations step. You just swap out the markdown files, and you're good to go. It's also worth noting that BlogDown supports custom renderers.